# Porting C to Go, having trouble understanding some pointer syntax

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, go

I'm currently porting some C (as part of a wider R package) to Go. Because the C in question is used as part of an R package, it has to make extensive use of pointers. The R package is [changepoint.np](https://github.com/cran/changepoint.np).

As somebody who isn't experienced in C, I've managed to understand most of it. However, the following code has me a bit stumped:

```
double *sumstat; /* matrix in R: nquantile rows, n cols */
int *n;          /* length of data */
int *minseglen;  /* minimum segment length */
int *nquantiles; /* num. quantiles in empirical distribution */

...[abridged for brevity]...

int j;
int isum;
double *sumstatout;
sumstatout = (double *)calloc(*nquantiles,sizeof(double));
for (j = *minseglen; j < (2*(*minseglen)); j++) {
    for (isum = 0; isum < *nquantiles; isum++) {
        *(sumstatout+isum) = *(sumstat+isum+(*nquantiles*(j))) - *(sumstat+isum+(*nquantiles*(0)));
    }
}
```

**Specifically, this line** (in the inner for loop):

```
*(sumstatout+isum) = *(sumstat+isum+(*nquantiles*(j))) - *(sumstat+isum+(*nquantiles*(0)));
```

I've read various pages and Stackoverflow questions/answers about C pointers and arrays, and if I understood them correctly, this line would be translated into Go as:

```
n := len(data)
nquantiles := int(4 * math.Log(float64(len(data))))

sumstatout[isum] = sumstat[isum*n + nquantiles*j] - sumstat[isum*n + nquantiles*0]
```

Where n is the number of columns (`*n` in the C code), and nquantiles is the number of rows (`*nquantiles` in the C code).

However this produces an error (index out of range, obviously) where the original code does not.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where does that `*n` come from? It isn't present in the original line.

Comment: I have been away from c for too long, but it seemed to me you multiply `isum` by `n` for no reason.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it more explicit. n is the length of the data (i.e. number of columns), nquantiles is the number of rows.

Comment: I am aware of the `*n` and its comment in C code, but the orignal c assignment to the array has no `n` in it at all, so why does your go code has it?

Comment: I was under the impression that *(arr+i+j) would be roughly analogous to arr[i][j] (array -> row -> col). To get the correct offset, I multiplied isum (the row value) by the number of elements in each row (n).

Comment: And it is unnecessary that an array stores by row order instead of col order.

Comment: Oops it is a terrible typo. I am so sorry. I mean `*(arr+i+j)` is just `arr[i+j]`. Sorry for the mislead.

Comment: So `*(sumstat+isum+(*nquantiles*(j)))` would be `sumstat[isum+(nquantiles*j)]`?

Comment: I don't envy you. Whoever wrote this code should be forced to maintain it, as punishment. On the bright side, looking at this code in Github, it seems to be a small project. Maybe you can rewrite from scratch without too much effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line:

```
sumstatout[isum] = sumstat[isum*n + nquantiles*j] - sumstat[isum*n + nquantiles*0]
```

I see two strange things:

1) Where did the `n` in `isum*n` come from? The `n` is not part of the orginal expression.

2) `nquantiles` is a pointer in the original code so it can't be used that way.

In C it should rather be:

```
sumstatout[isum] = sumstat[isum + *nquantiles*j] - sumstat[isum]
```

The original C code treats a (contiguous) memory area as a 2D matrix. Like this:

```
int i, j;
int cols = ..some number..;
int rows = ..some number..;
double* matrix = malloc(cols * rows * sizeof *matrix);
for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
        *(matrix + i*cols       +       j) = ... some thing ...;
                   ^^^^^^              ^^^
                 Move to row i        Move to column j
```

That is equivalent to:

```
int i, j;
int cols = ..some number..;
int rows = ..some number..;
double matrix[rows][cols];
for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        matrix[i][j] = ... some thing ...;
```

Comment: `sumstat` is a matrix in the R package, with `nquantile` rows and `n` columns. In the C (and in my Go port), they are analogous.

Comment: I thought that `*(sumstat+isum+(*nquantiles*(j)))` would mean (roughly speaking) `sumstat[isum][nquantiles*j]`, meaning to achieve the same thing in the Go version, I'd have to offset to the correct row (hence `isum*n`).

Comment: @johneth - the multiplication by `n` is wrong. See updated answer